Can we beat Grover for derangement problems?
Recall that a derangement of $N$ objects is (isomorphic to) a permutation of $\{1,\cdots, N\}$ that has no fixed point. The probability that a random permutation $f$ is a derangement rapidly reaches $\frac{1}{e}$, and the number of such permutations on $N$ objects is often labeled as $!N=\left\lfloor\frac{N!}{e}\right\rfloor$.
Certifying that $f$ is not a derangement is as simple as providing a preimage $a$ such that $f(a)=a$. Indeed if $f$ is a function from $n$ bits to $n$ bits (hence $N=2^n$), we can do Grover searching on the one's count of $x\oplus f(x)$. If Grover searching finds such an $a$ then $f$ is not a derangement, and $a$ is our witness.
But can we do better than the square-root speedup offered by Grover, as we know that $f$ is a permutation oracle, and we know how many such oracles are derangements?
I think it follows from the Aaronson-Ambainis conjecture that we couldn't get a superpolynomial speedup because even permutations likely don't have the structure needed for exponentiality, but could we get maybe a cube-root or better improvement for such a problem?

I'm fairly confident that the best algorithm is $O\left(\sqrt[3]{2^n}\right)$ because it quites resembles BHT, and there are other results on pseudorandom permutations that scale with a cubic root, but I haven't found a way to do the reduction for now :(
